Send error messages to catch with subprocess.check_output()
I'm writing a web app (app.py) that when calling an API, runs a python script (main.py).
I'm interested in two things:

Printing/logging the logs of main.py in real time to the console
Obtaining 'custom' error messages from main.py

Right now, I do the first point, and try to do the second, with:
@app.route('/run_script', methods=['POST'])
def run_script_now():
    main_path = str(Path("main.py").resolve())
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(["python", main_path], stderr=sys.stderr)
        msg = "Success", 200
        logger.info(msg)
        return msg
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        error_msg = f"Error: {e.stderr}"
        logger.critical(error_msg)
        return error_msg, 500

But e.stderr returns None and e.output returns Command '['python', 'C:\\Users\\main.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
And here's how I catch errors in main.py:
try:
        portfolio_summary = processing.process_portfolio_summary()
except Exception as ex:
        error_msg = str(ex)  # Get the error message
        sys_msg = f"Error en PortfolioSummary: {error_msg}"
        logger.error(sys_msg)
        sys.stderr.write(sys_msg)
        sys.exit(1)

logger.error(sys_msg) gets printed, but what I would expect is to e.stderr (app.py) have the value of sys_msg (main.py) but I can't get it to work.
Any ideas how I could implement it better?

Using stderr=sys.stderr prevents check_output() from capturing the error message in e.stderr

@Barmar even when removing stderr=sys.stderr the behavior is the same

Change stderr=sys.stderr to stderr=subprocess.PIPE
Using stderr=sys.stderr is the same thing as not supplying an argument at all; the default behavior of a subprocess is to write errors to stderr.
subprocess.PIPE is the way to pipe output from the subprocess to the parent, making it available in p.stdout and p.stderr (where p is a Popen object, or CalledProcessError in your case)

I tried that but it wouldn't print the logs in real time and would dump it all at the end.
To fix it, I imported the file as a module and ran it with main.run_process()
